# Sarimax endogenous and exogenous variables - Provided exogenous values are not of the appropriate shape

Tags: python, time-series, sarimax

The issue that I have is with a rather simple approach of forecasting time series in python using `SARIMAX` model and 2 variables:

- *endogenous*: the one of interest.
- *exogenous*: the one assumed to have some influence on the endogenous variable.

The example uses the daily values of BTC and ETH, where BTC is endogenous, and ETH is endogenous.

```
import datetime
import numpy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

import pandas as pd
import pmdarima as pm
import statsmodels.api as sm

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from datetime import date
from math import sqrt

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
import itertools
from random import random

import yfinance as yf
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

The method of fetching data is quite simple using yahoo.finance API as `yf`

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
ticker = input('Enter your ticker: ')
df1 = yf.download(ticker, period = 'max', interval = '1d')
df1.reset_index(inplace = True)
df1
```

This needs to be done manually - insert the name of the coin by hand (gives more freedom to the user in terms of what coins are combined).

```
Enter your ticker: BTC-USD
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed

    Date    Open    High    Low     Close   Adj Close   Volume
0   2014-09-17  465.864014  468.174011  452.421997  457.334015  457.334015  21056800
1   2014-09-18  456.859985  456.859985  413.104004  424.440002  424.440002  34483200
2   2014-09-19  424.102997  427.834991  384.532013  394.795990  394.795990  37919700
3   2014-09-20  394.673004  423.295990  389.882996  408.903992  408.903992  36863600
4   2014-09-21  408.084991  412.425995  393.181000  398.821014  398.821014  26580100
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2677    2022-01-15  43101.898438    43724.671875    42669.035156    43177.398438    43177.398438    18371348298
2678    2022-01-16  43172.039062    43436.808594    42691.023438    43113.878906    43113.878906    17902097845
2679    2022-01-17  43118.121094    43179.390625    41680.320312    42250.550781    42250.550781    21690904261
2680    2022-01-18  42250.074219    42534.402344    41392.214844    42375.632812    42375.632812    22417209227
2681    2022-01-19  42365.046875    42462.070312    41248.902344    42142.539062    42142.539062    24763551744

2682 rows × 7 columns
```

So `df1` is our *exogenous* data. Then the *endogenous* data are fetched in the same manner.

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
ticker = input('Enter your ticker: ')
df2 = yf.download(ticker, period = 'max', interval = '1d')
df2.reset_index(inplace = True)
df2
```

```
Enter your ticker: ETH-USD
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed

    Date    Open    High    Low     Close   Adj Close   Volume
0   2017-11-09  308.644989  329.451996  307.056000  320.884003  320.884003  893249984
1   2017-11-10  320.670990  324.717987  294.541992  299.252991  299.252991  885985984
2   2017-11-11  298.585999  319.453003  298.191986  314.681000  314.681000  842300992
3   2017-11-12  314.690002  319.153015  298.513000  307.907990  307.907990  1613479936
4   2017-11-13  307.024994  328.415009  307.024994  316.716003  316.716003  1041889984
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
1528    2022-01-15  3309.844238     3364.537842     3278.670898     3330.530762     3330.530762     9619999078
1529    2022-01-16  3330.387207     3376.401123     3291.563721     3350.921875     3350.921875     9505934874
1530    2022-01-17  3350.947266     3355.819336     3157.224121     3212.304932     3212.304932     12344309617
1531    2022-01-18  3212.287598     3236.016113     3096.123535     3164.025146     3164.025146     13024154091
1532    2022-01-19  3163.054932     3170.838135     3055.951416     3123.905762     3123.905762     14121734144

1533 rows × 7 columns
```

Now is a merging step where the two datasets are aligned.

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

data = df2.merge(df1, on = 'Date', how = 'left')
```

which looks like this:

```
    Date    Open    High    Low     Close_x     Adj Close   Volume  Close_y
0   2017-11-09  308.644989  329.451996  307.056000  320.884003  320.884003  893249984   7143.580078
1   2017-11-10  320.670990  324.717987  294.541992  299.252991  299.252991  885985984   6618.140137
2   2017-11-11  298.585999  319.453003  298.191986  314.681000  314.681000  842300992   6357.600098
3   2017-11-12  314.690002  319.153015  298.513000  307.907990  307.907990  1613479936  5950.069824
4   2017-11-13  307.024994  328.415009  307.024994  316.716003  316.716003  1041889984  6559.490234
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
1528    2022-01-15  3309.844238     3364.537842     3278.670898     3330.530762     3330.530762     9619999078  43177.398438
1529    2022-01-16  3330.387207     3376.401123     3291.563721     3350.921875     3350.921875     9505934874  43113.878906
1530    2022-01-17  3350.947266     3355.819336     3157.224121     3212.304932     3212.304932     12344309617     42250.550781
1531    2022-01-18  3212.287598     3236.016113     3096.123535     3164.025146     3164.025146     13024154091     42375.632812
1532    2022-01-19  3163.054932     3170.838135     3055.951416     3123.905762     3123.905762     14121734144     42142.539062

1533 rows × 8 columns
```

I want to focus solely on the closing price of BTC and ETH:

```
X = data[['Close_y',   'Date']]

y = data['Close_x']

X = pd.get_dummies(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1, random_state = 42, shuffle = False)

# grid search

X_train = X_train.drop('Date', axis = 1)
X_test = X_test.drop('Date', axis = 1)
```

Look for the best grid:

```
# Define the p, d and q parameters to take any value between 0 and 3 (exclusive)
p = d = q = range(0, 1)

# Generate all different combinations of p, q and q triplets
pdq = list(itertools.product(p, d, q))

# Generate all different combinations of seasonal p, q and q triplets
# put 12 in the 's' position as we have monthly data
pdqs = [(x[0], x[1], x[2], 12) for x in list(itertools.product(p, d, q))]

### Run Grid Search ###


def sarimax_gridsearch(pdq, pdqs, maxiter=5):


    ans = []
    for comb in pdq:
        for combs in pdqs:
            try:
                mod = SARIMAX(y_train, exog=X_train, order=comb, seasonal_order=combs)


                output = mod.fit(maxiter=maxiter)
                ans.append([comb, combs, output.bic])
                print('SARIMAX {} x {}12 : BIC Calculated ={}'.format(comb, combs, output.bic))
            except:
                continue

    # Find the parameters with minimal BIC value

    # Convert into dataframe
    ans_df = pd.DataFrame(ans, columns=['pdq', 'pdqs', 'bic'])

    # Sort and return top 5 combinations
    ans_df = ans_df.sort_values(by=['bic'], ascending=True)
    print(ans_df)
    ans_df = ans_df.iloc[0]


    return ans_df['pdq'], ans_df['pdqs']

o, s = sarimax_gridsearch(pdq, pdqs)
```

Make the predictions

```
# future predictions

# create Exogenous variables

df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1 = df1.set_index('Date')
df1 = df1.sort_index()
li = []
ys = ['Close']
for i in ys:
    a = df1[i]
    train_set, test_set = np.split(a, [int(.80 * len(a))])
    model = pm.auto_arima(train_set, stepwise=True, error_action='ignore',seasonal=True, m=7)
    b = model.get_params()
    order = b.get('order')
    s_order = b.get('seasonal_order')

    model = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(a,
                                      order=order,
                                      seasonal_order=s_order
                                      )

    model_fit = model.fit()

    start_index = data.index.max().date()+ relativedelta(days=1)
    end_index = date(start_index.year, start_index.month , start_index.day+10)
    forecast = model_fit.predict(start=start_index, end=end_index)

    #start_index = data.shape[0]
    #end_index = start_index + 12
    #forecast = model_fit.predict(start=start_index, end=end_index)
    
    li.append(forecast)

df = pd.DataFrame(li)
df = df.transpose()
df.columns = ys

df = df.reset_index()

exo = df[['Close', 'index']]
exo = exo.set_index('index')
```

But when I try to make the future predictions based on `exo`, like this:

```
#fit the model
print(b, s)
model_best = SARIMAX(y,exog=X.drop(['Date'],1), order=o, seasonal_order=s)

model_fit = model_best.fit()

model_fit.summary()

model_fit.plot_diagnostics(figsize=(15,12))

start_index = data.shape[0]
end_index = start_index + 12
pred_uc = model_fit.forecast(steps=13, start_index = start_index, end_index = end_index, exog = exo)

future_df = pd.DataFrame({'pred' : pred_uc})
print('Forecast:')
print(future_df)

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (8, 5)
#data = data.set_index('time')
plt.plot(data['Close_x'],color = 'blue', label = 'Actual')
plt.plot(pred_uc, color = 'orange',label = 'Predicted')
plt.show()
```

I get this annoying error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\mlemodel.py in _validate_out_of_sample_exog(self, exog, out_of_sample)
   1757             try:
-> 1758                 exog = exog.reshape(required_exog_shape)
   1759             except ValueError:

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 11 into shape (13,1)

 ValueError: Provided exogenous values are not of the appropriate shape. Required (13, 1), got (11, 1).
```

Can someone explain where I am wrong or what steps I missed in this module?

Comment: I got the same error, don't know how to fix it. I am running a SARIMAX on my y_train variable and the exogenous is the X_train. The error is `ValueError: Provided exogenous values are not of the appropriate shape. Required (74, 20), got (31, 20).`. How did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Check the shape of the `exo` variable. If you are forecasting 13 steps, then you need to provide `exog` variables for each of those 13 steps. The error message is saying that you only provided `exog` variables for 11 steps.  You can either provide a larger array to the `exog` argument, or you can change the forecast to be for 11 steps.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to do that and it works. However, when I want to predict for 30 days it says: ```      25     start_index = data.index.max().date()+ relativedelta(days=1)
---> 26     end_index = date(start_index.year, start_index.month , start_index.day+30)
     27     forecast = model_fit.predict(start=start_index, end=end_index)
     28 

ValueError: day is out of range for month```. Why is that? should I change the format of start.index?